# How can I use @ant-design/colors in scss files?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, antd

I want to use varibles from https://ant.design/docs/spec/colors in scss files

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rpUI.png)

Answer (score 1):

Since this question is tagged with [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) and [reactjs](/questions/tagged/reactjs), I'm going to assume you have some build system written in JavaScript to compile your scss files into CSS. If your build system is:

- [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) with [`sass-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-loader), consider using the [`additionalData` option](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-loader#additionaldata) to inject the color variables from the `@ant-design/colors` npm package.
- [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/), consider using the [`css.preprocessorOptions.scss.additionalData` option](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#css-preprocessoroptions) to inject the color variables from the `@ant-design/colors` npm package.
- [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com/) with [`gulp-sass`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass), consider using the [`data` option](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#data) to inject the color variables from the `@ant-design/colors` npm package.
- [Grunt](https://gruntjs.com/) with [`grunt-sass`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-sass), consider using the [`data` option](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#data) to inject the color variables from the `@ant-design/colors` npm package.
- Not mentioned above, you could try to include your own [custom Sass function](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/js-api/interfaces/Options#functions) that gets the desired color values from the `@ant-design/colors` npm package.

Comment: I'm using create-next-app

Comment: `create-react-app` generates the project with `react-scripts`. This uses Webpack. You may need to [eject your project](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/available-scripts/#npm-run-eject) first to modify the Webpack configuration or [see alternatives to ejecting](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/alternatives-to-ejecting).

Comment: Im using nextjs ( create-next-app )

Comment: Could you provide an aproximate example of  "custom Sass function" for this case, please ?

Comment: `import colors from '@ant-design/colors';` and then: `'ant-color($name, $shade)': ([nameRaw, shadeRaw]) => { const name = nameRaw.assertString('ant-color'); const shade = shadeRaw.assertString('ant-color'); const color = colors[name][shade]; return new sass.SassColor({ red: parseInt(color.substr(0, 2), 16), green: parseInt(color.substr(2, 2), 16), blue: parseInt(color.substr(4, 2), 16) }); },`

Comment: For me this sample doesnt work (
All code that you provided must be working inside js file ?

Comment: Yes, it would be a member of the `functions` object in the `options` argument object that you'd call one of the `compile*` functions with.

Comment: This function wont be reuseble, am I right ?

Comment: Still you sample is not working for me (

Comment: I have attached sreenshot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rpUI.png

Comment: You need to pass the function as a member of the `functions` object in the `options` argument object that you'd call one of the `compile*` functions with.

Comment: In this case, each time, when I need to use this function I have to create sass.compile, with provided path to the actual scss file? Am I right. If it is so, than it is not a resolution of the problem, because it is some kind of crutch )

Comment: No, you are not right. When using Sass, you call one of the `compile*()` functions to compile your Sass into CSS anyway. So this function would be added to the options when you call this function. You may be better off using the `additionalData`/`data` option as per the original answer.